# Modify all elements with the same tag name

Tags: javascript, html

In jQuery simply adding `$("div")` selects all elements with a tag name of `<div>`.
Suppose I wanted to do this in pure JavaScript, I would try entering this: `document.getElementsByTagName("div")`, but this only returns a list of elements. 

You cannot edit these elements all at once, you have to select them in order of occurrence, like so: `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[*occurrence*]`. 
**Is there any way to select all of these elements at once and store them in a variable?**

Thanks.

Comment: Do the same as jQuery does under the hood: iterate through the list and edit the elements one by one.

Comment: store them in a string? store them in an array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any way to select all of these elements at once and store them in a variable?

`getElementsByTagName` (or `querySelectorAll`) **is** how you do that.

But no, the DOM doesn't define functions that act on *lists* of elements the way jQuery does. You can, of course, write ones yourself.

```
function setValue(list, value) {
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
         list[n].value = value;
    }
};
```

jQuery's set-based approach is, I suspect, a big part of its appeal. That and the fact that by encapsulating sets of elements with mutators and accessors, it lets you chain things together. You could do that yourself, too, of course:

```
function MyList(selector) {
    this.elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
MyList.prototype.setAttr = function(attr, value) {
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
         this.elements[n].setAttribute(attr, value);
    }
    return this;
};
MyList.prototype.setHTML = function(html) {
    var n;
    for (n = 0; n < list.length; ++n) {
         this.elements[n].innerHTML = html;
    }
    return this;
};

// Usage
var list = new MyList("div");
list.setHTML("hi there").setAttr("data-foo", "bar");
```

Naturally those are quite primitive compared with jQuery's versions...

Comment: using prototypes is definitely a smarter way than my method because its reusable. Well done.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y0qxmjzy/) that shows how to use all found divs using a for ... in loop:

**HTML**

```
<div>text1</div>
<div>text2</div>
<div>text4</div>
<div>text3</div>
<span id="orderOfOutput"></span>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var allDivs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i in allDivs) {
    if (isNaN(i)) continue;//we only want the numbered indexes
    document.getElementById('orderOfOutput').innerHTML += '<span>Output div:' + allDivs[i].innerText + '</span><br />';
}
```

To store them in a variable just replace the innerHTML line with `divSelection[i] = allDivs[i];`

Comment: Nice answer, but not as sophisticated, and slightly more messy than the answer that I gave my vote too.

Comment: He definitely has the answer I would use. still +1s for good answers helps (not asking for it. just for future reference)